# Removing delimiter from JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, format, jspinner

I'm using a JSpinner for displaying years. Currently the JSpinner displays values above 1000 with a  delimiter. 1990 gets to 1.990.

I'm trying to set a custom NumberEditor to the JSpinner:

```
spBirthdayYear.setEditor(new JSpinner.NumberEditor(spBirthdayYear, "####"));
```

This doesn't work. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change [SpinnerModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html#model) for [JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html), and you could set [various formats](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/0580__JSpinner.htm)